# UART sending b'\x05' and receiving b'\x85'

Tags: c, byte, uart

My Attiny2313 is set up to echo the char received over UART, but when I send a b'\x05', I receive a b'\x85' from the Attiny.

I'm sending the byte via python

```
def initSerial(self, port):
    self._serialPort = port
    self._serial = serial.Serial(port, 9600, timeout=1)
    self._serial.write(b'\x05')
    receivedCmd = self._serial.readline()
    print(receivedCmd)
```

and the code on the Attiny that echoes

```
int main(void) {

    uint16_t c = 0;
    init_uart();
    
    sei();

    while (1) {

        c = uart_getc();
        if (c == UART_NO_DATA);
        else {
            uart_putc(c);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The uart.cpp file

```
/*
 * uart.cpp
 *
 * Created: 11/28/2021 10:36:27 PM
 *  Author: jonashoft
 */ 
#define F_CPU 1000000UL

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "uart.h"

#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0 
#endif

#define BAUD 9600

#define MYUBBR ((F_CPU / (BAUD * 16L)) - 1)
#define BUFFER_SIZE 16

volatile static uint8_t rx_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
volatile static uint8_t tx_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
volatile static uint8_t rx_head = 0;
volatile static uint8_t rx_tail = 0;
volatile static uint8_t tx_head = 0;
volatile static uint8_t tx_tail = 0;
volatile static uint8_t sent = TRUE;


/*
 * init_uart
 */
void init_uart(void) {
  // set baud rate
  UBRRH = (uint8_t)(MYUBBR >> 8); 
  UBRRL = (uint8_t)(MYUBBR);
  // enable receive and transmit
  UCSRB = (1 << RXEN) | (1 << TXEN) | (1 << RXCIE);
  // set frame format
  UCSRC = (1 << USBS) | (3 << UCSZ0);   // asynchron 8n1
}



/*
 * send_uart
 * Sends a single char to UART without ISR
 */
void send_uart(uint8_t c) {
  // wait for empty data register
  while (!(UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)));
  // set data into data register
  UDR = c;
}



/*
 * receive_uart
 * Receives a single char without ISR
 */
uint8_t receive_uart() {
  while ( !(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)) ) 
    ; 
  return UDR; 
}



/*
 * uart_getc
 * Gets a single char from the receive buffer.
 * return   uint16_r    the received char or UART_NO_DATA 
 */
uint16_t uart_getc(void) {
  uint8_t c = 0;
  uint8_t tmp_tail = 0;
  if (rx_head == rx_tail) {
    return UART_NO_DATA;
  }
  tmp_tail = (rx_tail + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
  c = rx_buffer[rx_tail];
  rx_tail = tmp_tail;
  return c;
}



/*
 * uart_getc_f
 * getc in stdio style.
 */
int uart_getc_f(FILE *stream) {
  uint16_t c;
  while ((c = uart_getc()) == UART_NO_DATA) {}
  return c;
}



/*
 * uart_getc_wait
 * Blocking call to getc. Will not return until a char is received.
 */
uint8_t uart_getc_wait(void) {
  uint16_t c;
  while ((c = uart_getc()) == UART_NO_DATA) {}
  return c;
}



/*
 * uart_putc
 * Puts a single char. Will block until there is enough space in the
 * send buffer.
 */
void uart_putc(uint8_t c) {
  uint8_t tmp_head = (tx_head + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
  // wait for space in buffer
  while (tmp_head == tx_tail) {
    ;
  }
  tx_buffer[tx_head] = c;
  tx_head = tmp_head;
  // enable uart data interrupt (send data)
  UCSRB |= (1<<UDRIE);
}



/*
 * uart_putc_f
 * Puts a single char. Used by printf functions.
 */
int uart_putc_f(char c, FILE *stream) {
  uart_putc(c);
  return 0;
}



/*
 * uart_puts
 * Sends a string.
 */
void uart_puts(const char *s) {
  while (*s) {
    uart_putc(*s);
    s++;
  }
}



/*
 * uart_puts_P
 * Sends a PROGMEM string.
 */
void uart_puts_P(const char *s) {
  while (pgm_read_byte(s) != 0x00) {
    uart_putc(pgm_read_byte(s++));
  }
}



/*
 * ISR User Data Regiser Empty
 * Send a char out of buffer via UART. If sending is complete, the 
 * interrupt gets disabled.
 */
ISR(USART_UDRE_vect) {
  uint8_t tmp_tail = 0;
  if (tx_head != tx_tail) {
    tmp_tail = (tx_tail + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
    UDR = tx_buffer[tx_tail];
    tx_tail = tmp_tail;
  }
  else {
    // disable this interrupt if nothing more to send
    UCSRB &= ~(1 << UDRIE);
  }
}



/*
 * ISR RX complete
 * Receives a char from UART and stores it in ring buffer.
 */
ISR(USART_RX_vect) {
  uint8_t tmp_head = 0;
  tmp_head = (rx_head + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
  if (tmp_head == rx_tail) {
    // buffer overflow error!
  }
  else {
    rx_buffer[rx_head] = UDR;
    rx_head = tmp_head;
  }
}
```

The uart.h file

```
/*
 * uart.h
 *
 * Created: 11/28/2021 10:36:11 PM
 *  Author: jonashoft
 */ 
#ifndef UART_H_
#define UART_H_

#include <stdio.h>

#define UART_NO_DATA 0x0100

// Initialize UART to 9600 baud with 8N1.
void init_uart(void);

// Send and receive functions, that run without ISRs
uint8_t receive_uart();
void send_uart(uint8_t c);

// Receive a single char or UART_NO_DATA, if nothing received
uint16_t uart_getc(void);
// Blocking call to receive a char
uint8_t uart_getc_wait(void);
int uart_getc_f(FILE *stream);

// Send a single char
void uart_putc(uint8_t c);
int uart_putc_f(char c, FILE *stream);

// Send a string
void uart_puts(const char *s);
// Send a PROGMEM string
void uart_puts_P(const char *s);

#endif /*UART_H_*/
```

Im uncertain about how to handle the received byte in C, because I assumed it would just be a hex value and I therefore could check `if (c == 0x85)` but that didn't trigger. How we I handle the received value? I want to check if the sent byte was either 1, 2,.. 5 (b'\x01', b'\x02', ..)

Sending the echo of b'\x05', 0x22 and 0x10 from the Attiny, results in receiving b'\x85\xa2\x90' in python. This communication is shown here on the oscilloscope

[image: oscilloscope result]

I think the problem resides in the code, because when I try to send 0x01, 0x02 and 0x03 from the C code, python receives 0x81, 0x82, 0x31. Also when the C code sends 0x09, 0x10 and 0x11, python receives 0x89, 0x90 and 0x91

Comment: It looks like you have race condition bugs all over the place, and in addition missing `volatile` qualifiers to prevent incorrect optimizations. Here's a post explaining both the use of `volatile` and race condition bugs: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102

Comment: I'm sorry, race condition bugs? I'm fairly new to electronics, so I'm not sure what you mean. Also where would you place the volatiles?

Comment: Ohh you're faster than me, thanks

Comment: Using interrupts isn't trivial, I'd probably recommend to study multithreading on a PC first, to understand the meaning of race conditions. Multithreading basically comes with the same problems as hardware interrupts, though the means to prevent bugs caused by concurrent execution are different between PC and embedded systems. If you ever end up using RTOS it's the same deal there too.

Comment: I want to use interrupts, I want to learn interrupts. Also I checked, all the variables used in ISR and functions, are volatile. Could there be any other reason as why I receive something else than expected

Comment: You do not show any included header, function prototypes or global variables. Maybe it would help to show all the missing code.

Comment: Do you have some logic analyzer or oscilloscope to view the UART line? You could check if you already send a wrong value from the Attiny or even to the Attiny. Or maybe the baudrate does not match and the extra bit is an early stop-bit that is interpreted as data bit. Also did you verify that all other values are echoed OK?

Comment: I have tested sending 1 to 5 from python and receives b'\x81' to b'\x85'. Also I just tested sending 0x22 and 0x10 from the C code right after the echo, and received b'\x85\xa2\x90'. The result of this in the oscilloscope is in the post now

Comment: Your ATTiny UART initialization has `UCSRC = (1 << USBS) | (3 << UCSZ0);   // asynchron 8n1`.  That's a bogus comment, since the configuration is actually for 8N**2**.  Suggest that you change the code (for the number of stop bits) to match the comment.  BTW you are not a computer, so phrases such as *"when I send..."* and *"I receive..."* would make more sense if replaced by the device (PC host?) that you are using.